# Does the __restrict allow to ignore the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

Let's say that I have a buffer of chars and I want to avoid using memcpy, and access to it through an int* variable:

```
char buffer[100];
strcpy(buffer,"Hello");
int* __restrict ptr=(int*)buffer;
*ptr= 97;
printf("%s",buffer);
```

Now this of course prints "a".
Am I allowed to do this without encountering an undefined behaviour?

Comment: I think you're going in the wrong direction. If anything, the `restrict` is going to make the compiler *more* likely to "break" something since it assumes no aliasing.

Comment: Indeed. `restrict` makes the aliasing rules much more strict; you're not allowed to alias the pointer **at all** except using pointers "based on" it (in a clever definition of the concept of being "based on"). Not even with pointers to the same type or `char` type pointers. Of course pointers of other types are still not allowed to alias it either.

Comment: So do I still have to use unions?

Comment: Note that `__restrict` is a non-standard compiler-specific extension.  `restrict` is a standard keyword only in C99 and C11, but *not* in C89 or any current edition of C++.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: you never had to use unions. `int val = 97; memcpy(buffer, &val, sizeof(val));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now this of course prints "a".

Well, only on little endian machines.

And strict aliasing would have nothing do with your example as one of the type is `char` and `char` may alias anything if the goal of `restrict` wasn't to **increase** the number of cases where the compiler may assume that there is no alias, i.e. even when typing information wouldn't prevent it.

And obviously if you want information about `__restrict` which is in the implementation domain, you should specify the implementation.